# Why any of highcharts demo example doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts

I'm trying to use highcharts [example](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-negative/). But it doesn't work, I cannot understand, have I missed something?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML><html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Highcharts Example</title>

</head>

<body>

    <h1>Highcharts example</h1>
    <div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>   


    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#container').highcharts({
                chart: {
                    type: 'column'
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Column chart with negative values'
                },
                xAxis: {
                    categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas']
                },
                credits: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                series: [{
                    name: 'John',
                    data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2]
                }, {
                    name: 'Jane',
                    data: [2, -2, -3, 2, 1]
                }, {
                    name: 'Joe',
                    data: [3, 4, 4, -2, 5]
                }]
            });
        });    
    </script>

</body></html>
```

I've already tried to play with this paths, but no matter:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
```

How to set a right path? For example, I use path like "*highcharts/js/highcharts.js*" and it's real exist in a project directory.

Comment: Works fine for me: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/cLECd Look in the [JavaScript error console](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners) and tell what errors you see there and which lines they point to.

Comment: thanks a lot, I've realy looking for some javascript debugger and you links seem great for this. I see you point, may be it is problem with cloud9ide, but some of other examples worked well there.

Answer (score 1):

You missed the

```
</html>
```

tag at the end.

However, your code on a fiddle works well.

Comment: Sorry It doesn't past.

Answer (score 0):

I just copied your code and paste it in a html file. It's working very fine.

```
Here is the screenshot
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, as I understand it's problem with IDE which I use